# Modal Loading com Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin

Estou criando um aplicativo com Xamarin e quero criar um Modal de Loading enquanto faço uma busca no WebService. Pesquisei alguns exemplos que usam Page Modal e outros com PopUp. Agora estou tentando criar com o plugin Rg.Plugins.PopUp mas não estou tendo sucesso, o PopUp não abre.

Qual a melhor maneira para fazer isso ?

**PopUp Page**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pages:PopupPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    x:Class="CooperativaApp.View.PopUpLoading"
    CloseWhenBackgroundIsClicked="False">
    <!--You can set an animation in the xaml file or in the csharp code behind-->
    <pages:PopupPage.Animation>
        <animations:ScaleAnimation 
            PositionIn="Center"
            PositionOut="Center"
            ScaleIn="1.2"
            ScaleOut="0.8"
            DurationIn="400"
            DurationOut="300"
            EasingIn="SinOut"
            EasingOut="SinIn"
            HasBackgroundAnimation="True"
            />
    </pages:PopupPage.Animation>
    <!--You can use any elements here which are extended from Xamarin.Forms.View-->
    <StackLayout 
        VerticalOptions="Center" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center" 
        Padding="20, 20, 20, 20">
        <ActivityIndicator             
            IsRunning="True"
            IsVisible="True"
            Color="Green"/>
    </StackLayout>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

**Tela de Login**

```
private void OnClickAcessar(object sender, EventArgs args){     
            //abre o popup loading
            PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new PopUpLoading());

            //objeto usuario
            Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
            usuario.login = "admin";
            usuario.pswd = "admin";

            //consulta login webservice
            UsuarioService service = new UsuarioService();
            service.doLogin(usuario);

            //fecha o popup loading
            PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();
        }
```

Comment: Olá fernando, você precisa informar mais detalhes sobre sua aplicação, pois olhando sua implementação está correta. Você realizou as configurações obrigatórias do plugin? https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: @ViniciusDutra o problema era que tinha q colocar o metodo como `async` e usar `await` na chamada do popup. Fiz isso e funcionou !

Comment: Que ótimo @Fernando, pode fechar a pergunta então se seu problema foi resolvido